# OpenDaylight Application Developer’s tutorial ping fails

Tags: ping, mininet, opendaylight

ubuntu@sdnhubvm:~$ sudo mn --topo single,3 --mac --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13 --controller remote

s1 ovs-ofctl add-flow tcp:127.0.0.1:6634 -OOpenFlow13 priority=1,action=output:controller

mininet> h1 ping h2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

what is the problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

The L2Switch project provides Layer2 switch functionality.

Running the L2Switch project
Check out the project using git

```
git clone https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/p/l2switch.git
```

The above command creates a directory called "l2switch" with the project.

Run the distribution
To run the karaf distribution, you can use the following command:

```
./distribution/karaf/target/assembly/bin/karaf
```

NOTE: if karaf doesn't boot up to console,It is suggested to clear the contents of distribution/target/assembly/data/cache

To run the base distribution, you can use the following command

```
./distribution/base/target/distributions-l2switch-base-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-osgipackage/opendaylight/run.sh
```

If you need additional resources, you can use these command line arguments:

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m'
```

Creating a network using Mininet

```
sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=<Controller IP> --topo=linear,3 --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13

sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1 --topo=linear,3 --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13
```

The above command will create a virtual network consisting of 3 switches. Each switch will connect to the controller located at the specified IP, that is to say, 127.0.0.1.

```
sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1 --mac --topo=linear,3 --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13
```

The above command has the "mac" option, which makes it easier to distinguish between Host MAC addresses and Switch MAC addresses.

Generating network traffic using Mininet

```
h1 ping h2
```

The above command will cause host1 (h1) to ping host2 (h2)

```
pingall
```

'pingall' will cause every host to ping all other hosts.